# Posting Slackbot response in Golang

Tags: go, slack-api

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkB_c3cgtd0&t=1186s) tutorial trying to get the go slack lib working. I am able to receive messages from slack, stored in `ev` variable but can not reply

```golang
    func replyToUser(ev *slack.MessageEvent) { //change this to the channel for the actual app
    fmt.Printf(ev.User)

    slackClient.PostMessage(ev.User,
        slack.MsgOptionText("hello world", false),
        slack.MsgOptionUser(ev.User),
        slack.MsgOptionAsUser(true),
        slack.MsgOptionUsername("songbot"),
    )
}
```

I am passing the event i receive from slack to this function and hoping to reply with a `hello world`. I am using a classic slackbot.

Currently getting the error:

```sh
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x127abb7]
```

Any help much appreciated !

Comment: Are you certain that you pass a non nil `*slackMessageEvent`. Remove the post message and just leave the printf. If it doesnt print this is defently the problem

Answer (score 0):

really sorry I incorrectly defined the slack client. Full answer here: https://github.com/slack-go/slack/issues/796

Running code is:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/slack-go/slack"
)

var (
    slackClient *slack.Client //initialise the slack event
)

func main() {
    slackClient = slack.New(os.Getenv("SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN"))
    rtm := slackClient.NewRTM() //create the realtime messaging objext
    go rtm.ManageConnection()   // set it up in a go routine

    for msg := range rtm.IncomingEvents {
        switch ev := msg.Data.(type) {
        case *slack.MessageEvent:
            go handleMessage(ev)
        }
    }
}

func handleMessage(ev *slack.MessageEvent) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ev)
    fmt.Printf("Text Received: %v\n", ev.Msg.Text)
    _, _, err := slackClient.PostMessage(ev.Channel, slack.MsgOptionText("message", false), slack.MsgOptionAsUser(true))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error sending to slack: " + err.Error())
    }
    return
}
```